# Firestore transactions with security rules making reads

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create two documents

```
Account/{uid} {
    consumerId: ... //client generated id
}

Consumer/{consumerId} {
    ...
}
```

and I have a security rule for the consumer collection

```
match /Consumer/{consumerId} {
    allow create: if (consumerId == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Account/$(request.auth.uid)).data['consumerId'];
}
```

I need to ensure that an account can only add a consumer document with a `consumerId` corresponding to the one in their Account document. Both documents should be created together. I've been trying to do this with transactions but I keep getting the error "Transaction failed all retries.". Whats going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: you ever get an answer?

Comment: @AKnox unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The data variable is an object and not an array, so you should use `data.consumerId` instead of `data['consumerId']`:

```
match /Consumer/{consumerId} {
    allow create: if consumerId == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Account/$(request.auth.uid)).data.consumerId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The documentation states you can access the index either way. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/ (under 'Index'). The problem seems to be that the Account collection doesn't contain the document yet even though it's written before the Consumer document in my transaction. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this with a batch write and security rules.

```
match /consumer/{cid} {
  function isNewResource() { return resource == null; }

  allow create: if isRegistered();
  allow read, update: if isNewResource();
}
```

And then client side with something along the lines of

```
createThing() {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const { uid, displayName } = this.auth.currentUser;
  const batch = this.db.batch();

  // Essentially generating a uuid
  const newConsumerRef = db.collection("consumer").doc();

  // Update the user doc
  batch.update(
    db.collection('/users').doc(uid),
    { consumerID: newConsuemrRef.id }
  );

  // Update the admins field in the new doc
  batch.set(newConsumerRef, {
    admins: {
      [uid]: displayName,
    },
  });
  return batch.commit();
}
```

My problem was the same, but the write to the field in the collections actually needed to be to an object key, so it looked a little funkier

```
batch.update(
    db.collection('/users').doc(uid), 
    { [`adminOf.${newRef.id}`]: 'some special name' }
);
```